# SaveInstanceState on radiobuttons from menu

Tags: android, save, radio-button

I was wondering how I can use SaveInstanceState to save the state of a radio button in the menu_main,  so it will save whether the button is clicked or not, even after the app closes.

```
 <group
    android:checkableBehavior="single"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_invert_colors_white_24dp"
    android:id="@+id/invert"
    android:title="Invert">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/mYellow"
        android:orderInCategory="1"
        android:title="Amber/Teal"
        app:showAsAction="never" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/mGreen"
        android:orderInCategory="2"
        android:title="Green/Mango"
        app:showAsAction="never" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/mRed"
        android:orderInCategory="3"
        android:title="Crimson/Indigo"
        app:showAsAction="never" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/mBlue"
        android:orderInCategory="4"
        android:title="Blue/Magenta"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
</group>
```

Comment: I think we need to see more code...

Comment: @Harrimf : For this -> 'even after the app closes' What you exactly want? save state after application close or save state when orientation will changed of device?

Comment: Please add more code, is it your options menu?

Comment: @MamataGelanee I mean when the application closes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Save state even application close

To implement this scenario you have to save state in SharedPreferences.

use below code :

```
 public static void setSharedPrefString(Context context, final String key, final String value){
        SharedPreferences radioState = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = radioState.edit();
        editor.putString(key, value);
        editor.apply();
    }

    public static String getSharedPrefString(Context context, final String key, final String defaultValue){
        SharedPreferences radioState = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        return radioState.getString(key, defaultValue);
    }
```

Save state of radio button as a value to your key.

**Key** : It can be any static final string like "radioStaste" like Json key.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks I will try to apply it!

Comment: @Harrimf : Please check if you do not know about 'Accept Answer' -> http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer